# Error scp from local machine to aws ec2 using ansible "command" module

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

i am using asnible shell module to scp the directory from my local to newly created ec2 instance.
And i am facing below error.

=====

```
- name: Installer to cloud instance
  shell: /usr/bin/scp -i {key} -r {dir} -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no LogLevel=quiet ec2-user@ '{{  ec2.instances[0].public_dns_name }}:'/tmp/
```

=====

Error : "Please login as the user "ec2-user" rather than the user "root\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error it look like the user you are passing is not being used

I found a space char right after the `ec2-user@`, which might be the problem.

in question

> shell: /usr/bin/scp -i {key} -r {dir} -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no LogLevel=quiet ec2-user@ '{{  ec2.instances[0].public_dns_name }}:'/tmp/

try:

> shell: /usr/bin/scp -i {key} -r {dir} -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no LogLevel=quiet ec2-user@'{{  ec2.instances[0].public_dns_name }}:'/tmp/